# How to split a string and save the 2 characters that I split with?

Tags: java, split

I am trying to split a given string using the java split method while the string should be devided by two different characters (+ and -) and I am willing to save the characters inside the array aswell in the same index the string has been saven.

for example :

input : `String s = "4x^2+3x-2"`

output : 

`arr[0] = 4x^2
arr[1] = +3x
arr[2] = -2`

I know how to get the + or - characters in a different index between the numbers but it is not helping me,
any suggestions please?

Comment: Does `(?<=[^+-])(?=[+-])` work?

Answer (score 2):

You can face this problem in many ways. I´m sure there are clever and fancy ways to split this expression. I will show you the simplest problem-solving process that can help you.

**State the problem you need to solve, the input and output**

```
Problem: Split a math expression into subexpressions at + and - signals 
Input: 4x^2+3x-2
Output: 4x^2,+3x,-2
```

**Create a pseudo code with some logic you might think works**

```
Given an expression string
Create an empty list of expressions
Create a subExpression string
For each character in the expression
Check if the character is + ou - then
add the subExpression in the list and create a new empty subexpression
otherwise, append the character in the subExpression
In the end, add the left subexpression in the list
```

**Implement the pseudo-code in the programming language of your choice**

```
    String expression = "4x^2+3x-2";
    List<String> expressions = new ArrayList();
    StringBuilder subExpression = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
        char character = expression.charAt(i);
        if (character == '-' || character == '+') {
            expressions.add(subExpression.toString());
            subExpression = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(character));
        } else {
            subExpression.append(String.valueOf(character));
        }
    }
    expressions.add(subExpression.toString());
    System.out.println(expressions);
```

Output

```
[4x^2, +3x, -2]
```

You will end with one algorithm that works for your problem. You can start to improve it.

Comment: This answer uses a *parser* solution rather than a regular expression, which is - in the end - probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
String s = "4x^2+3x-2";

s = s.replace("+", "#+");
s = s.replace("-", "#-");
String[] ss = s.split("#");

for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    Log.e("XOP",ss[i]);
}
```

This code replaces `+` and `-` with `#+` and `#-` respectively and then splits the string with `#`. That way the `+` and `-` operators are not lost in the result.

If you require `#` as input character then you can use any other Unicode character instead of `#`.

Comment: also you can't lose + or - from your array

Comment: thanks you @MaartenBodewes for your suggestion appreciate it

Comment: thanks for help @MaartenBodewes now my answer look like some experienced write it thank you so much brother

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like it better to have *positive* matches of patterns, especially if the `split` pattern itself is empty.

So for instance you could use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|[+-])([^+-]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("4x^2+3x-2");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("%s or %s %s%n", m.group(), m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

This matches the start of the string or a plus or minus: `^|[+-]`, followed by any amount of characters that are *not* a plus or minus: `[^+-]*`.

Do note that the `^` first matches the start of the string, and is then used to negate a character class when used between brackets. Regular expressions are tricky like that.

Bonus: you can also use the two groups (within the parenthesis in the pattern) to match the operators - if any.

All this is presuming that you want to use/test regular expressions; generally things like this require a *parser* rather than a regular expression.

---

A one-liner for persons thinking that this is too complex:

```
var expressions = Pattern.compile("^|[+-][^+-]*")
        .matcher("4x^2+3x-2")
        .results()
        .map(r -> r.group())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
String s = "4x^2+3x-2";
String[] arr = s.split("[\\+-]");
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: This both matches an earlier answer *and* it has the same problem of not matching the output requirements.